# How can we use two different serializers in a single generics.ListAPIView while overriding get_queryset() method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, view, django-serializer

My `Views.py`

```
class RelatedFacultyProfile(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FacultyProfileGenericSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        helper = UserTypeHelper(self.request, path=False)
        if helper.user_type == 'F':
            queryset = Faculty.objects.filter(department=self.request.user.faculty.department)
        if helper.user_type == 'S':
            queryset = Faculty.objects.filter(department=self.request.user.student.branch)        
        return queryset


class RelatedStudentProfile(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = StudentProfileGenericSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        helper = UserTypeHelper(self.request, path=False)
        if helper.user_type == 'F':
            queryset = Student.objects.filter(branch=self.request.user.faculty.department)
        if helper.user_type == 'S':
            queryset = Student.objects.filter(branch=self.request.user.student.branch)        
        return queryset
```

I want to combine the querysets of these two views to generate a single JSON response which will require two different serializers
So how to achieve this ?

Comment: The question is not that clear. You wanna use two serializers, lets say SerializerA and SerializerB in one APIView class, lets say RelatedFacultyProfile? Am I right ?

Comment: @SreenathP you are absolutely right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the [DjangoRestMultipleModels](https://github.com/MattBroach/DjangoRestMultipleModels) package. Specifically for your use `ObjectMultipleModelAPIView` will be the right choice. It has the added benefit of pagination so you get performance benefits when querying the querysets.

Also, override the get_querylist() function like so

```
def get_querylist(self):
    helper = UserTypeHelper(self.request, path=False)
    if helper.user_type == 'F':
        querylist = [{'queryset': Faculty.objects.filter(department=self.request.user.faculty.department), 'serializer_class': FacultyProfileGenericSerializer},
                    {'queryset': Student.objects.filter(branch=self.request.user.faculty.department), 'serializer_class': StudentProfileGenericSerializer}]
    if helper.user_type == 'S':
        querylist = [{'queryset': Faculty.objects.filter(department=self.request.user.student.branch)), 'serializer_class': FacultyProfileGenericSerializer},
                    {'queryset': Student.objects.filter(branch=self.request.user.student.branch), 'serializer_class': StudentProfileGenericSerializer}]
    
    return querylist
```